# WinAppDriver is throwing org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, office-automation, winappdriver, selenium-java

I am new to winAppDriver and was trying what was taught on one of the tutorial. However, I am getting org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 400. Message: Bad capabilities. Specify either app or appTopLevelWindow to create a session exception.

```
    package openWindowsApps;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.appium.java_client.windows.WindowsDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.windows.options.WindowsOptions;

public class OpenCalculator {
    private WindowsDriver windowsDriver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void openCalculator() throws InterruptedException, MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("app", "C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe");
        // desiredCapabilities.setCapability("app",
        // "Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("platformname", "Windows");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "WindowsPc");

        windowsDriver = new WindowsDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), desiredCapabilities);
        windowsDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(20));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void clickOnButtons() {
        System.out.println("Clicking on buttons");
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() {
        windowsDriver.quit();
    }

}
```

P.S: I have downloaded the WinAppDriver.exe and was trying to automate opening the calculator app. I also heard that WinAppDriver does not work with Selenium 4 hence have used selenium 3.

Edit: I am also not getting driver.findElement(By.AccessibilityId) on autosuggestion even though I have installed the following dependency.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```